# Visual Studio Code - file icon color

Tags: visual-studio-code

After updating to VS Code 1.46.1. I see 2 diffs. color of .js files. There is no code change in any of the files then why 1 js file icon is yellow and others are orange. What's the meaning of these 2 different colors?

[image]

This is the default theme which is auto-enabled after installation.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I look at the file name closely, All files with extension *.test.js looks orange and the other js file looks yellow. This is vs code way to differentiate the type of files. vs code knows and tries to show the difference between normal js file and .test.js files. Although we can write test cases in any js files but *.test.js files are special test cases file.

Also, check this link https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension

It says the *.test.js files have access to the VS Code API.